# Broadcasted summing on cell arrays - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vectorization, cell-array

Suppose I have a matrices `C1,C2` as follows:

`C1 = nx2 cell` each cell is `[5x5 double]`.

`C2 = 1x1 cell` contain a `[5x5 double]`.

How to calculate `C3` as:

```
C3{1,1} =  C1{1,1}+C2{1,1};
C3{1,2} =  C1{1,2}+C2{1,1};
          .
          .
C3{n,2} =  C1{n,2}+C2{1,1};
```

using `cellfun` or any other method without looping

Comment: If you want to keep your question unclosed: ask a good, on-topic question:P Anyway: `cellfun(@(x) x+C2{1,1},C1,'uniformoutput',false)` probably. But you'll have trouble with `C1{n,n}` in your example if `C1` is indeed `nx2 cell`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straightforward use of [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) does exactly what you want:

```
C3 = cellfun(@(x) x+C2{1,1},C1,'uniformoutput',false);
```

This will essentially loop over each element of the cell array `C1`, and for each element apply the anonymous function `@(x) x+C2{1,1}`, i.e. each element will be added to `C2{1,1}`. The resulting elements are returned in a cell array of the same size as `C1`.

---

For a few smaller test cases I compared this solution to that [suggested by @Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34405449/5067311). The result is not trivial, since both `cellfun` and `cat` (used in Divakar's solution) are (in)famously slow. I threw in a third version to check, in which I defined a temporary variable in my anonymous function:

```
tmpvar=C2{1,1};
C3a2=cellfun(@(x) x+tmpvar,C1,'uniformoutput',false);
```

The rationale behind this is that accessing that single cell element should have some overhead, and I'm unsure whether the entire cell is pulled into the workspace of the anonymous function.

I defined a separate function to test the three cases in order to let JIT do its job (but note that I'm using R2012b, a newer version could give quite different results, with [the new execution engine and everything](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/matlab-execution-engine/)). I ran all three cases on the same random input (with a `C2` cell array of size `[1,1]` and containing an array of the same size as `C1{k,l}`), choosing the shortest runtime from 10 attempts (based on `tic/toc`).

1. `5x5` cell array of `10x10` matrices:

   - `cellfun`:                  `0.000452 s`
   - `cellfun`+`tmpvar`: `0.000287 s`
   - `bsxfun(cat)`:          `0.002970 s`
2. `5x5` cell array of `100x100` matrices:

   - `cellfun`:                  `0.000988 s`
   - `cellfun`+`tmpvar`: `0.000963 s`
   - `bsxfun(cat)`:          `0.004661 s`
3. `10x10` cell array of `5x5` matrices:

   - `cellfun`:                  `0.001580 s`
   - `cellfun`+`tmpvar`: `0.000945 s`
   - `bsxfun(cat)`:          `0.011358 s`
4. `100x100` cell array of `5x5` matrices:

   - `cellfun`:                  `0.108276 s`
   - `cellfun`+`tmpvar`: `0.082675 s`
   - `bsxfun(cat)`:          `1.132417 s`

Based on these small test cases I'm tempted to conclude that

1. Using a temporary variable in the anonymous function given to `cellfun` can indeed count if the larger cell array is large, which makes sense (since then the function is evaluated a larger number of times).
2. The `bsxfun(cat)`-based solution is a bit slower for small cell arrays, and much slower for larger cell arrays. I suspect that `cat` is to blame: it takes a lot for `cat` to put the extra dimension together. I could even imagine that using a loop with preallocation might outperform `cat`.
3. It would be interesting to check the same for the new execution engine, and on much larger (`n>1000`) matrices and cell arrays.

Comment: Accessing cell arrays and indexing in general to the same location repeatedly has its own penalty, so that `tempVar` is a smart addition. Would love to get hands dirty with this new JIT thing myself, seems like people are talking about it!

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I'm looking for

Answer (score 3):

For cases like those when you have regular sized arrays, you should be preferably using multi-dimensional arrays rather than slow cell arrays. Sticking with the cell arrays though, here's one vectorized solution using [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) as the basis of vectorized broadcasted summations after converting them to multi-dimensional arrays -

```
%// Store size of each cell and size of C1 for later reshaping purposes
[m,n] = size(C1{1,1})
[nr,nc] = size(C1);

%// Perform broadcasted summations with BSXFUN
sums = bsxfun(@plus,cat(3,C1{:}),C2{1,1})

%// Reshape and convert back to cell arrays as desired output 
out = reshape(mat2cell(sums,m,n,ones(1,nr*nc)),nr,nc)
```

Comment: `n` is `cell_nrows` and `cell_ncols` in the last line, respectively. Right?:) And should `cat`+`bsxfun` still be faster than `cellfun`?

Comment: @AndrasDeak Thanks! That `C1{n,n}` in the OP had me confused, edited the solution. There is some setup involved here before and after performing the actual summations, so I guess it would depend a lot on the actual test case. Bring in huge `n` and it might be interesting :)

Comment: (ancient) R2012b: `(m,n,nr,nc)==(5,5,10,10)`: 0.003482 s `cellfun` vs  0.016824 s `bsxfun(cat)`.  (100,100,10,10)`: 0.006484 s vs  0.024914 s. `(10,10,100,100)`:  0.109620 s vs 1.158193 s. (My memory use is...suboptimal, so I didn't venture to check much larger sizes)

Comment: @AndrasDeak Hmm thanks for benchmarking! Seems like `cellfun` is the way to go! Or just re-structure data into multi-dimensional arrays as the setup to vectorization isn't really helping it seems.

Comment: @AndrasDeak BTW consider posting that cellfun method as an answer. As OP stated, that might be what he/she is looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I did just that. To make up for it, I also added a bit more proper comparison.